# Sorting in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting, key

how can i sort(based on name) this list of objects in typeScript ?
`"[{name:"Prasanna",age:"22",sex:"Male",Designation:"System Engineer",Location:"Chennai"},     {name:"Nithya",age:"21",sex:"Female",Designation:"System Engineer",Location:"Chennai"},     {name:"Rajesh",age:"24",sex:"Male",Designation:"Senior System Engineer",Location:"Mysore"},     {name:"Priya",age:"20",sex:"Female",Designation:"System Engineer",Location:"Bangalore"},     {name:"Raja Raghul",age:"21",sex:"Male",Designation:"System Engineer",Location:"Hydrabad"}]`"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function. You need to pass a callback to tell the sort function how to compare the elements in the array.

`var a = /* your array */ ;
a.sort(function(x, y) { return x.name <= y.name ? -1 : 1; });`

The callback takes two arguments, that are elements of the array, and returns a negative number if `x < y`, 0 if `x == y` and a positive number if `x > y`. For more details, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description). For our case, we compare the strings lexicographically and return either -1 or 1.

This works for JavaScript. There is nothing specific to TypeScript in this question.

Comment: could you explain how Sort function is working in above sutivation ?